# WatchKit 1 apps aren't supported on this version of watchOS. Quitting "(null)"

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, swift5, watchos

I have shifted my watchOS (swiftUI) project form Intel mac 2016 to Mac M1 2020. Project is working fine on Intel mac but on M1 app start crashing after start with this error message on console log.

**WatchKit 1 apps aren't supported on this version of watchOS. Quitting "(null)"**

Comment: Facing the same issue with apple watch project.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.

In my situation everything was set correctly on Watch App target.

But under Watch Extension there was a "arm64" entry in Excluded Architectures section.

Removing that entry solved the problem (as M1 Simulator is arm64).

Answer (score 0):

I set User Defined -> VALID_ARCHS to $(ARCHS_STANDARD) and that helped.

Answer (score 0):

Go to project WatchKit app `build phases` and **UNCHECK** `copy only when installing`

This solution for me to run in simulator.

[image]