# Watch App getting crashed in M1 chip with watchos 8.5

Tags: ios, swift, watchos, watchos-8

Watch App getting crashed while running in M1 mac.

Xcode - Version 13.3.1 (13E500a) 
watchOs - 8.5

> **`WatchKit 1 apps aren't supported on this version of watchOS. Quitting "(null)"`**

Previously we are using intel chip mac, It's working fine.
After updating to the M1 chip we are facing the above issue.

I know the same kind of question is raised already but that answer does not helpful for me.
[WatchKit 1 apps aren't supported on this version of watchOS. Quitting "(null)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67380107/watchkit-1-apps-arent-supported-on-this-version-of-watchos-quitting-null)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WatchKit 1 apps aren't supported on this version of watchOS. Quitting "(null)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67380107/watchkit-1-apps-arent-supported-on-this-version-of-watchos-quitting-null)

Comment: @meaning-matters This answer is not resolved for us.